# Server Storage - Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, local-storage

I have the following problem: I have Java application - Sprint boot, which uses Angular in the frontend. This application needs to store some data on the client side, however, this data is lost when the client changes their browser or opens an anonymous browser tab.

I need an alternative, other than linking data to the user in the database. Something that is implemented in Java itself.

Is there any way I can store data in Java - Even though I know they will be volatile, that is, we can assume that my application server will be up 100% of the time.

**edit

My server run a openshift plataform that have multiple pods, the load baancer of server are configured in a NON-Sticky sessions design. That's why we can assuming that my server will be 100% active.

Comment: need more information

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the design of your server. For example, why is it guaranteed to be up 100% of the time? Do you have multiple redundant instances? In that case you need to coordinate that "storage" between all instances; you may even want to deal with a quorum of instances keeping the state etc. Doesn't seem to be trivial. Or do you have just one single instance? But how do you guarantee 100% uptime?

I strongly recommend using some kind of data store or at least distributed cache.

Comment: Yes, my server run a  openshift plataform that have multiple pods, the load baancer of server are configured in a NON-Sticky sessions design. That's why we can assuming that my server will be 100% active.